# Socorro com esse enigma terrível para um iniciante!

Tags: python

Quero identificar os números impares, porem deixando com uma formatação no print sem espaços em branco

EX:**"Esses são os ímpares:(1, (), 3, '')"** quero que mostre assim:
**"Esses são os ímpares: 1, 3,"**

**Segue o código para melhor compreensão:**

```
soma=0
a=int(input('Diga um número:\n'))
a1=int(input(''))
a2=int(input(''))
a3=int(input(''))
if a%2==1:
    soma+=a
    b=a
else:
    soma+=0
    b=()
if a1%2==1:
    soma+=a1
    b1=a1
else:
    soma+=0
    b1=()
if a2%2==1:
    soma+=a2
    b2=a2
else:
    soma+=0
    b2=()
if a3%2==1:
    soma+=a3
    b3=a3
    
else:
    soma+=0
    b3=('')   
print(f'Soma dos ímpares: {soma}')

print(f'Esses são os ímpares:{b,b1,b2,b3}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra ser sincero, o código está bem confuso... Vou tentar passar algumas dicas e demonstrar como eu faria. De logo, está com uma lógica bacana, mas é bom evoluir mais algumas aulas pra ver o básico (condicionais e repetições).

Se você colhe 4 variáveis, na verdade não precisa dar 1 if para cada uma... você deve utilizar um laço de repetição para facilitar o seu código (pode usar o FOR se souber quantas vezes precisa repetir e o WHILE se não tiver certeza).

Outra coisa que você deveria utilizar seria uma lista para guardar os números ímpares, através do comando append.

Tentarei colocar um código simples que você conseguirá ver várias coisas novas (lista e laço). Nesse caso você consegue facilitar muito o código deixando-o da seguinte forma:

```
impares = []
for numero in range(0, 4):
    num = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    if num % 2 == 1:
        impares.append(num)
        print(f'{num} é um número impar')
    else:
        print(f'{num} não é um número impar.')
print(impares)
```